# Exception rendering qute template

Tags: java, quarkus

I am trying to render a qute template inside a method:

```java
@ResourcePath("myTpl")
Template tpl;

void generate(Order order) { 
   tpl.data("order", order).render(); 
}
```

The template file:

```html
{@org.acme.Order order}

<html>
...
{#for orderProduct in order.getProducts()}
   <tr>{orderProduct.getPrice()}</tr>
{/for}
...
</html>
```

The issue that I am facing:

`[error]: Build step io.quarkus.qute.deployment.QuteProcessor#analyzeTemplates threw an exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a virtual method: *(orderProduct`

Thanks.

Comment: can I see a reproducer in github ?

Comment: Same issue https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/6369

Comment: I don't think it's the same issue. It only has a similar error message caused by a parsing error.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, file a new issue and attach a minimal reproducer. And don't forget to mention the Quarkus version. BTW you should be able to use `{#for orderProduct in order.products}` and `{orderProduct.price}` instead (no param -> no need to use the parentheses).